# Integral of a Kernel function

Tags: integration

I try to understand p.334 question 9-1 in Cameron Trivedi ([link](http://www.centroportici.unina.it/centro/Cameron&Trivedi.pdf)) where I have to calculate the bias of a Kernel density estimate at x=1 and n=100, where we assume that the underlying density is standard normally distributed **N(0,1)**. The Kernel is uniform, that is we have

$$K(v)=0.5\times 1(|v|<1)$$

where **v** is defined as $$(x_i-x)/h$$ and **1** is the indicator function that is either 1 if evaluated true and 0 otherwise. h is the bandwidth and given to be 1.0 in this example.

The bias of the Kernel is then "simply" obtained as

$$bias = 0.5h^2f''(x)\int v^2 K(v)dv$$

This doesn't seem to difficult at first. I know h, I can calculate f''(1) from the normal distribution analytically. However, I am stuck to get the integral(s) of this uniform Kernel. Is there a standard trick, a table or anything that can help me estimating it? I could do it numerically but I believe it should be possible to do it analytically too...

ps this is not a homework question, just curiosity how to apply Kernel density estimates without relying on numerical computations. Related to that, how would I integrate just

$$\int K^2(v)dv$$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information here the integral in question is just $0.5\int_{-1}^1 v^2dv=1/3$ ?

Comment: I am confused how did you "integrate a Kernel", it's an inequality that depends on v. Should you not use some product rule etc.?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it's an inequality"? A Kernel in this case is just a function and you are considering it as a function $v$. In terms of $v$ if you plot $K(v)$ it is zero everywhere except between $-1$ and $1$ and between which it is 0.5.

Comment: So I just ignore K(v).. do the integral of the rest and that's it? How would I do it with Gaussian Kernel that where v is in the power e^(f(v)).. There I would certainly use the product rule?

Comment: No you do not ignore $K(v)$ - it is a function that is zero everywhere and equal to 0.5 between -1 and 1. So the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} vK(v)dv=0.5\int_{-1}^{1}v^2=1/3$. The function $K(v)$ is part of the integral its just that its zero over most of the domain and a constant over the rest.

Comment: ohh I see... If I have more complicated Kernels , like Triangular, Gaussian etc. I would need to then evaluate the integral analytically, treating v as a variable. For example Triangualr is given by (1-|v|)1(|v|<1)... Do I need then to simply evaluate the integral v^2*(1-|v|) for -1 to 1?

Comment: Yes for other Kernels you would need some other trick probably. But you still treat the Kernel as a function. The integral as you note in the case of a Guassian would be on something like $v^2 exp(f(v))$. Yes, to the triangle case. Both can be computed without much difficulty.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.. I was confused about how exactly treat the Kernel within an integral.. Thinking that since K(v) is a function, I thought I would need have to use a chain rule or whatever and then end up with multiple Kernels...

Comment: One more question though.. how would I integrate just K^2(v) ? Under the integral I would have then 0.25*[1(|v|<1)}^2.Would I in this case just do the same and treat it as unity since as you said it must be definitely one under the integral...?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is as follows.

$E \hat f(x) = \frac{1}{h} E K((x-X_1)/h) = h^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^\infty K((x-t)/h) f(t) dt$.

Now substitute $v=(x-t)/h$ to obtain

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(v) f(x+vh) dv$

Expanding (Taylor), noting that $h\to 0$ and that $K$ is symmetric around zero and integrates to one gives

$f(x) + (h^2/2) f''(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(v) v^2 dv$.

Your specific kernel equals 0.5 on $[-1,1]$ and zero elsewhere, which gives

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(v) v^2 dv= 0.5 \int_{-1}^1 v^2 dv = 1/3$,

as noted by others.

Comment: thanks, great answer.. although only the last part is relevant for actually integrating the Kernel.. I have no fully figured the whole thing and recalculated all delta values given in the table for most Kernels. I was confused about the indicator function and how to treat it. Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is one more thing that is interesting regarding the question. They ask about the bias at x=1. However, at x=1 the second derivative of the pdf normal distribution is zero. Hence, the bias is actually zero, regardless of the Kernel.

Comment: No, actually.  The bias then converges as $h^4$.

Comment: Why would it converge? f''(1)=0, h=1 and given, the integral of the kernel function is a constant 0.333. The bias is therefore zero at the inflexion point at x=1 it seems to me... this makes intuitively sense as when there is no inflexion, there is no under or oversmoothing possible.

Comment: Because what the OP calls the bias is just the dominant term in an asymptotic bias expansion, but it ceases to be dominant if $f''(1)=0$.

Comment: What is the bias at f(1) then? Intuitively since there is no inflexion, in other words the density is a straight line at that very point, any smoothing should not underrate or overrate the true value. I bet if we expand the bias to all possible terms and evaluate it numerically, we end up at ->0 regardless. But you write it converges as h^4? Why is that and not h^2?

Comment: Just take more terms in the Taylor expansion and you get $h^4$ times the fourth derivative at $x$ times a constant, which is nonzero.

Comment: yes, but those cancel each other out. Any Taylor expansion is an approximation when cut of at a higher derivative. The whole as a sum however is zero at the inflexion point. Hence, the bias is zero at x=1, if we don't do a Taylor expansion and the the bias at face value.